# How do I log every method that's called in a Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, logging, methods

I've inherited a large pile of Ruby code that's, frankly, close to impossible to understand for a mortal like myself.  It's actually Rspec unit test code, but the structure is "highly unusual" to put it nicely.

What I'd like to be able to do is run the code, and have the following information logged somewhere:

- every method that gets invoked, including the name of the class that defines the method, and the filename where the invoked method has been defined (yep, we've got the same class/method defined in multiple different files, and it's tough to know which is being invoked)
- (optionally) the parameters passed to each method invoked

With that, I could start trying to refactor it.  Without it, it's going to be a very difficult task to get it straightened out, due to the size of the code base (20k+ unit test cases).

I can't afford to go in and perform wholesale edits to the code being run, because it breaks when you even use harsh language around it (i.e. frequently).  Instead, I need to be able to instrument the code in its existing state, or with minimal changes to what exists now.

Is there a way of logging this level of detail without making wholesale changes to the code base?  I've had a look at the Ruby profiler to see if it could help, and it probably could; I'm curious if there's a better way (particularly logging the filename containing the invoked method).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered a static analyzer or are you only looking for something that actually runs the code? Doxygen outputs some nice caller/callee graphs, haven't looked to see if it supports Ruby but call graphs can prove very useful for understanding existing code.

Comment: I'm fairly sure Doxygen doesn't support Ruby - if it did, it would certainly be useful to me, but I can't find any info about Doxygen supporting Ruby.

I'd prefer to have something that actually runs the code, primarily because the order in which require's get processed will affect which of the multiple (non-identical) definitions of a given method will be used.

As I said, it's an ugly code base...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is definitely possible -- in fact, there's even a method for it! Just add this somewhere in your code before the point that you want to start logging things:

```
set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  printf "%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", event, file, line, id, classname
}
```

The secret sauce you want comes from **[`Kernel#set_trace_func`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005939)**, as noted above:

> - set_trace_func(proc) => proc
> - set_trace_func(nil) => nil
>
> Establishes `proc` as the handler for tracing, or disables tracing if the parameter is `nil`. `proc` takes up to six parameters: an event name, a filename, a line number, an object id, a binding, and the name of a class. `proc` is invoked whenever an event occurs. Events are: `c-call` (call a C-language routine), `c-return` (return from a C-language routine), `call` (call a Ruby method), `class` (start a class or module definition), `end` (finish a class or module definition), `line` (execute code on a new line), `raise` (raise an exception), and `return` (return from a Ruby method). Tracing is disabled within the context of proc.

Here's a handy example:

```
class Test
  def test
    a = 1
    b = 2
  end
end

set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  printf "%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", event, file, line, id, classname
}

t = Test.new
t.test
```

(Note: don't try this in `irb` unless you want a huge scrolling screen of text.) The resulting output is:

```
    line test.rb:11               false
  c-call test.rb:11        new    Class
  c-call test.rb:11 initialize   Object
c-return test.rb:11 initialize   Object
c-return test.rb:11        new    Class
    line test.rb:12               false
    call test.rb:2        test     Test
    line test.rb:3        test     Test
    line test.rb:4        test     Test
  return test.rb:4        test     Test
```

You can play around with the formatting string above to get just the results you want to log (for example, it sounds like you're only interested in `call` events).

Comment: Wow - that's ... exactly what I was hoping for.  Thanks John!

Comment: No problemo. Ruby turns out to be quite handy with this sort of Swiss-Army-knife stuff.

Answer (score 25):

Recently, `set_trace_func` was deprecated:

> Note: this method is obsolete, please use TracePoint instead.

We can use TracePoint, which backs `set_trace_func`, instead:

```
trace = TracePoint.new(:call) do |tp|
  puts "#{tp.defined_class}##{tp.method_id} got called (#{tp.path}:#{tp.lineno})"
end

trace.enable
# do stuff here
trace.disable
```

This is actually even more powerful than `set_trace_func` because you can enable and disable at your convenience. You can selectively hook into the following events: `:line, :class, :end, :call, :return, :c_call, :c_return, :raise, :b_call, :b_return, :thread_begin, :thread_end`

Here a full example:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
  end
  def y
    z
  end
  def z
   1 + 1
  end
end

trace = TracePoint.new(:call) do |tp|
  puts "#{tp.defined_class}##{tp.method_id} got called (#{tp.path}:#{tp.lineno})"
end

trace.enable # note
MyClass.new.y
trace.disable
  # MyClass#initialize got called (./trace.rb:4)
  # MyClass#y got called (./trace.rb:7)
  # MyClass#z got called (./trace.rb:10)
```

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to include the seconds-past-the-minute the event happend at as well as how long was spent in each function

```
start = DateTime.now.strftime('%Q').to_i / 1000.0
set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  now_ms = DateTime.now.strftime('%Q').to_i / 1000.0
  duration = '%.3f' % (now_ms - start)
  start = DateTime.now.strftime('%Q').to_i / 1000.0
  printf "%s %s %8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", DateTime.now.strftime("%S.%L"), duration, event, file, line, id, classname
}

AdminUser.create(password: "password", password_confirmation: "password", email: email)

set_trace_func nil
```

I was trying to debug why it took so long to create users and log into ActiveAdmin.

```
05.761 0.000 c-return /Users/nperry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rxair/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7/lib/bcrypt/engine.rb:51       to_s   String
05.761 0.000   c-call /Users/nperry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rxair/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7/lib/bcrypt/engine.rb:51 __bc_crypt BCrypt::Engine
09.736 63.975 c-return /Users/nperry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rxair/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7/lib/bcrypt/engine.rb:51 __bc_crypt BCrypt::Engine
09.736 0.000   return /Users/nperry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rxair/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7/lib/bcrypt/engine.rb:59 hash_secret BCrypt::Engine
09.736 0.000   c-call /Users/nperry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rxair/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7/lib/bcrypt/password.rb:46        new    Class
```

And from that I know Ruby spent more than a minute in `__bc_crypt`.

Comment: Sounds like you have a pretty high Bcrypt `cost`. T.J. Shuck has [a nice video explaining this](http://rubyvideos.com/presenters/t-j-schuck) (the first 15 minutes or so).

Comment: I believe we did resolve this issue at the time and the issue was definitely Bcrypt.